Laravel gates only take first item in array
This is my app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php
public function boot(): void
    {
        Gate::define('hasRole', function ($user, $roles) {
            dd($roles);
            return in_array($user->role_type, (array) $roles);
        });
    }

and inside a controller I use
 if (!Gate::allows('hasRole', ['Admin', 'Manager'])) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
        }

but this dd() only shows first item of array 'Admin' why?

Finally found a solution by myself. Keeping it here for future users who might come up with this issue.
 Gate::define('hasRole', function ($user, $roles) {
            if (!is_array($roles)) {
                $roles = func_get_args();
                array_shift($roles); // Remove $user from arguments
            }
            return in_array($user->role_type, $roles);
        });

and this is how I used.
if (!Gate::allows('hasRole', ['Admin'])) {
    abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
}

